# Nginx client certificate authorization

Tags: authentication, ssl, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I have to configure Nginx to accept client self-signed certificates. 
The problem is that certificates should be prepared by clients themselves and signed by them. I know drawbacks of such approach but this is customer requirement. 
Currently Nginx is configured to accept client certificates signed by my own CA(untrusted). ssl_client_certificate points to ca.crt. 
Customer wants about 100 client certificates, each of them signed by a different untrusted CA - not chained.
How should I configure Nginx to work in that way? I believe I should prepare file containing each client cert, CA cert. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [CACert](http://www.cacert.org/)? That way each client can generate their certificate (easier than doing on their own) and you hold only one CA at `ssl_client_certificate`.

Otherwise, you'll have to concatenate all of the CAs at the file pointed out for `ssl_client_certificate`.

Alternatively, you can issue with your CA intermediate CAs for each user (then each one generates their certificate), and you use only your CA at `ssl_client_certificate`, and specify the correct `ssl_verify_depth`:

```
ssl_verify_client      on; # or optional
ssl_verify_depth       2; # >1, depending on your CA chain
```